# Не удается опубликовать приложение уровня данных SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Имеется две базы данных:

- локальная - (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB (SQL Server 12.0.2000)
- в azure -
  sitename.database.windows.net (SQL Server 12.0.2000)

Раньше я делал "Извлечение приложения уровня данных" из второй базы, а затем "Публикация приложения уровня данных" в локальную. Все выполнялось без ошибок.

Вчера обновил Visual Studio до последней версии, и теперь при выполнении этой процедуры я получаю ошибку

> Проект, где указана целевая платформа База данных SQL Microsoft Azure
>   версии 12, не может быть опубликован в SQL Server 2014

Делаю все манипуляции через SQL Server Explorer в студии.

**UPD:** обе базы создавал давно, еще до выхода обновлений, уровни совместимости должны совпадать (120)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несмотря на совпадающую версию, в Azure SQL V12 включены некоторые из новых фич SQL 2016. Поэтому в Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 проверку совместимости между Azure SQL и SQL Server поменяли на более строгую.

Если вы ничем из новых фич не пользуетесь - просто отключите проверку совместимости - выставьте Allow Incompatible Platform в Advanced Publish options.

Статья в Microsoft Connect на эту тему: [Database project - cannot deploy to local SQL 2014](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2552394/database-project-cannot-deploy-to-local-sql-2014)

Comment: А в дальнейшем, если понадобятся эти фичи, нужно будет базу публиковать уже на SQL Server 2016?

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев да. ну или можно просто сейчас обновить локальный сервер до 2016 - у вас localdb, он бесплатный.